# how to do Single sign on in Magento2

Tags: magento2, magento2.2

Can Someone explain how single sign on can be done programmatically in magento2. Or the application logic of single sign on? We have multiple site these sites are in different technology for example one site is in wordpress another in java. So when a customer signed in either wordpress or java application then the same customer when he move to store should be signed in automatically. How this can be implemented?

Comment: Hey Bridgit, just want to clarify what you mean by "Sign on" do you mean Signing in or signing up?

Comment: Its like when we have multiple sites but in any one site when user login, the user will be logged in to all other site automatically.

Comment: Alright, I think you should add that information to your question to avoid confusion